# Disable all the inputs, and buttons inside a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Is there a way to disable all the `input`s, `button`s, `select`s inside a react component on the basis of a state variable, or a prop of the component?

- My react component has multiple such buttons, and inputs.
- Some of them are rendered `disabled` on some boolean state variable, say `bool1` as:

  ```
  <button disabled = {bool1}>Button 1</button>
  ```
- Some buttons are rendered `disabled` on some boolean state variable, say `bool2` as:

  ```
  <button disabled = {bool2}>Button 2</button>
  ```
- Similarily, there are multiple elements that behave disabled on the basis of some state variable.

But what I want is, I have a state variable `isCompDisabled`, which when `true`, should disable all the inputs and buttons, etc. But, when it is `false`, the button or input should then revert back to its state as decided by the other boolean variable. This behaviour can be implemented by adding a conditional for every element. **In short, the behaviour should be like:**

```
<button disabled = {boolX || isCompDisabled}>Button X</button>
```

The problem in my use case is, that it would be lengthy process going to each input or button, and add a disabled logic on it. Is there a short way, or an entire other way of fulfilling my use case?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap all your inputs in a `<fieldset>` and use the `disabled` attribute there instead:

```
<fieldset disabled={boolX || isCompDisabled}>
  // Your inputs and buttons...
</fieldset>
```

Note that form elements inside the `<legend>` element won't be disabled.

See the [fieldset documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset).